How does 'std::add_const' work when I instantiate it with 'const int'?
The following code snippet comes from libstdc++'s implementation of std::add_const,
/// add_const
template<typename _Tp>
struct add_const
{ typedef _Tp const     type; };

If I use int to instantiate std::add_const, then I will get the following, and it makes sense.
struct add_const
{ typedef int const     type; };

But, If I use const int to instantiate std::add_const, then it seems to me that I will get the following:
struct add_const
{ typedef const int const     type; };

For the above code, I will get duplicate const and it is a syntax error.
May I ask if I have any knowledge of blind spots about that?
I searched for related questions but didn't find the answer I wanted.
I am not a native English speaker, so please correct me if my expression is unclear.

templates is not macros, its not just text substitution. This is more like what happens when the template is instantiated: https://godbolt.org/z/djfc6rs7v

For the const int case, the type remains unchanged, even though you apply add_const on it!

It has nothing to do with add_const. Your confusion is about how typedef works.

The same vay typedef const int X; typedef const X Y; has always worked.

@Yksisarvinen (PS redundant cv-qualifications introduced by typedefs are allowed and would be ignored). This sentence answered my doubts, thank you very much.

Dupe: Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored.


For the above code I will get duplicate const and it is a syntax error.[...] ?

No, For the T as const int case, the type remains unchanged (ie. const int), even though you apply std::add_const on it. The standard ensures that redundant const qualifiers are ignored.
That means, the following all end up in the same type: const int
const const int
const const const int
const int const
const int const const
int const const
int const const const
// .. so on ...

The same happens in the typedef std::add_const as well. From cppreference.com:
 template< class T > 
 struct add_const;  (2) (since C++11)


Provides the member typedef type which is the same as T, except it has a cv-qualifier added (unless T is a function, a reference, or already has this cv-qualifier)

You could have simply check it:
#include <type_traits> 


static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<std::add_const_t<int>, 
                   std::add_const_t<const int>>, "are not same!");  // passes


OP is asking explicitly about an implementation, so you should probably account for that in your answer as well.
